# Is it possible now to make something for android in Unity3d without buying any licenses?

Tags: android, unity

I was just talking to a game dev who said its possible, that it involves downloading the android sdk and few other things. If this is possible can someone tell me how?

Also is it possible to build a .apk file and install on your device? Is it possible to release something developed this way on the play store?

Comment: you can compare licenses (FREE/PRO) here:
http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses Dynamic shadows by themselves are worth the pro license.

Comment: Yeah from my previous understanding of that you get android basic with unity pro, and I was assuming u need at least that to build for android, but then I heard otherwise. Btw dynamic ray traced shadows are in free unity now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Nowadays it is possible to develop for mobile platforms even with Unity Free. There is a good guide available: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html

It is also possbile to build an .apk file and install it on your device. Once you have set up Unity & Android SDK just a simple build will generate the .apk file.

And final yes, you can develop for Play-store.